# delta potential stationary functions momentum measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, fourier-transform

I need help solving Cohen Tannoudji's Ex2 in section $K_I$.

> We have a stationary state of the delta function potential $V_0\delta(x)$ with wave function 
>   $$\psi(x)=\sqrt\frac{mV_0}{\hbar^2}e^{-\frac{mV_0}{\hbar^2}|x|}.$$
>   The question is: What is the probability to measure the momentum to be within $[p,p+\Delta p]$?

To my best understanding i'm supposed to take to fourier transform $\tilde{\psi}(p)$ and then calculate $\intop_{p}^{p+\Delta p}|\tilde{\psi}(p)|^2dp$.

The problem is that this become very cumbersome and eventualy I get a reault that is linear with $\Delta p$ while I would expect a result that gets closer to 1 (or some other constant)q when $\Delta p \rightarrow\infty$.

Finally, I'm asked to estimate $\Delta x \Delta p$ to which I would like to get a clue.

Comment: for the first part - thats what I did but when I expand the $\arctan$ it seems the first member is not enough and the second is already too much.

for the second part - why is  FWHM is enough for the Lorentzian?

Comment: [Accidentally deleted comment] The Fourier transform should give you a Lorentzian, which is $\propto \frac{1}{p^2}$. Integrating that over the range should give you something like $\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{\hbar^2\Delta p}{\pi mV_0}\right)$. For the second part you can probably use a full-width-half-max for the two distributions.

Comment: Why are you expanding it? The first term is linear in $p$, but the whole series goes to $\pi/2$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. For the second part, I would think FWHM would give you a decent order-of-magnitude estimate, which is all the exercise asks for.

Comment: @KyleArean-Raines becuaue im integratin from $p$ to $p+\Delta p$ i shoud get something like $\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\frac{\hbar^2(p+\Delta p)}{\pi mV_0})-\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan(\frac{\hbar^2\Delta p}{\pi mV_0})$ so I need to expand, no?

Comment: You can probably just use $\arctan(u) \pm \arctan(v) = \arctan \left( \frac{u \pm v}{1 \mp uv} \right)$